# Can't connect to an AWS EC2 instance with cURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can anyone tell me why can't I connect to an AWS EC2 instance?

I am using cURL to connect like this:

`curl ec2-54-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

But I am getting the following error:

`curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong? I haven't previously worked with AWS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be many things:

1. Review the **AWS Security Groups**. You probably need to add an incoming traffic exception rule for port 80 in the Security Group that's attached to your instance. For more information [refer to the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html).
2. If your EC2 instance is in a VPC, you need to make sure networking has been set up properly with an Internet Gateway and proper Routing Table rules. For reference, there is a nice example of a typical VPC setup [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html).
3. Additionally, if the above don't solve the issue, check the EC2 instance's OS firewall rules and that the HTTP server is running.

Comment: Ok I will check into that

Comment: When I run `ufw status` on server it shows: `Status: inactive`

Comment: Did you check the security group rules for your instance on your AWS console?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the firewall on your server which is blocking the connection. Are you able to curl any other website

Comment: Yes I am able to curl to other website. How can I check firewall on the server?

Comment: When I run `ufw status` on server it shows: `Status: inactive`

Answer (score 0):

If you are curling an FTP URL then you may need to set the FTP Passive port range and open the range in your Security group.

Credit: [Setting up FTP on Amazon Cloud Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server)