# FTP Login Example PHP to Amazon EC2 using AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have gone through many articles but none of them cleared my doubt. I am new to Amazon SDK. My requirement is to connect to AMAZON EC2 instance through php is there any way in SDK to connect through ftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK would have nothing to do with connecting to your instance via FTP. To do that you need to install an FTP server on your instance, configure it correctly for the environment and use standard ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

Just like datasage said in his answer, you need to install some FTP server to your EC2 instance. For example vsftpd is quite simple ftp server software to configure.

In a nutshell, you need to (depending on your Linux distribution on the EC2 instance...)

- `sudo yum install vsftpd`
- configure the /etc/vsftpd.conf
- add ftp users/accounts
- make sure that TCP ports 20, 21 (and possibly the ports for passive ftp) are opened from the EC2 console's security settings

A nice detailed installation procedure is described in this older question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404078/5526468