# How create ftp user to give access /var/www for amazon ec2 ubuntu AMI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I have setup ec2 ubuntu server successfully. Able to connect ec2 instance via ftp as well. But that is the default "ubuntu" user and gives control to all system. So I want to create a new user and allow them access to `/var/www` folder and they can not see anything else. Even sharing a private key is dangerous. I have been googling for last one day but not able to find any solution. Don't have much linux server knowledge but by following steps, I able to achieve it.

I created one user with password via terminal, allowed set that new user's home dir to `/var/www` and tried to connect via filezilla. But could not connect and gives error `ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did to set up ftp, but you probably want to install and configure vsftp.  There is a very good summary of steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server).

Comment: I have't set up any ftp or did not installed any new packages for that. Its default with ubunt@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx it was given in aws documentation.