# Create FTP user to access /var/www/html/uploads folder to write from PHP programs

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, centos7

I did setup FTP and created user and changed home directory to /var/www/html as stated in below link.

[Setting up FTP on Amazon Cloud Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server)

Now, I can connect FTP but I can't see files list, unable to upload files to /var/www/html folder.

Comment: By the way, when i try to upload file am getting below error.        Response: 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
Command: STOR thankyou.php
Response: 553 Could not create file.

Comment: what is the outpu tof `ls -ld /var/www/html`, and what user are you uploading as?

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to do here -

1) Check your vsftpd.conf file and look for line chroot_local_user, it should be set to yes.

2) Check for permissions on files and folders under /var/www/html.