# How do I access pyftpdlib FTPS server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ftp, ftp-server, pyftpdlib

I am trying to create a simple FTPS server on my Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance using the Python library pyftpdlib.

Here is the code straight from the documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
An RFC-4217 asynchronous FTPS server supporting both SSL and TLS.
Requires PyOpenSSL module (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL).
"""

from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.contrib.handlers import TLS_FTPHandler
import os


def main():
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_user('ubuntu', '*****', os.getcwd(), perm='elradfmw')
    authorizer.add_anonymous('.')
    handler = TLS_FTPHandler
    handler.certfile = 'keycert.pem'
    handler.authorizer = authorizer
    handler.masquerade_address = '52.23.244.142'
    # requires SSL for both control and data channel
    handler.tls_control_required = True
    handler.tls_data_required = True
    handler.passive_ports = range(60000, 60099)
    server = FTPServer(('', 21), handler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the script on my Amazon EC2 instance and when I try to connect remotely using FileZilla, I get:

```
Status: Connecting to 52.23.244.142:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 pyftpdlib 1.4.0 ready.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS successful.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER ubuntu
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Username ok, send password.
Command:    PASS *****
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   501 Invalid argument.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ=0 successful.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 Protection set to Private
Command:    OPTS MLST type;perm;size;modify;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
Response:   200 MLST OPTS type;perm;size;modify;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to: Binary.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering passive mode (52,23,244,142,174,172).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 File status okay. About to open data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I think I am missing something. Can I get some help?

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can access the same ftp server running on my local machine. But can not access the ftp server running on my ec2. Why?

Comment: Why? What happens? Any error message?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Just added the error message at the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your server must present its external IP address in the response to the `PASV` command. You instead present an internal IP address within the EC2 private network, to which the FileZilla obviously cannot connect to.

   While FileZilla can workaround that:

   > Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

   other FTP clients (like the Windows command-line `ftp.exe`) cannot.

   Use the [`handler.masquerade_address`](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyftpdlib.handlers.FTPHandler.masquerade_address) to configure the external IP address:

   ```
   handler.masquerade_address = '52.23.244.142'
   ```
2. FileZilla cannot connect to the port 50048 (195 << 8 + 128). You have probably not opened ports in an FTP passive mode port range in the EC2 firewall.

   See [Setting up FTP on Amazon Cloud Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7052875/850848) (particularly section *"Step #2: Open up the FTP ports on your EC2 instance"* in [the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7052875/850848#11404078)).

   To avoid opening whole unprivileged port range, limit the FTP server to use a smaller port range using [`handler.passive_ports`](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyftpdlib.handlers.FTPHandler.passive_ports):

   ```
   handler.passive_ports = range(60000, 60099)
   ```

---

For a general information see *my* article about the [network setup in respect to FTP passive (and active) connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

Comment: Let's say I have a website sitting on 52.23.244.142 as well. What exact address do I point an ftp client to for their transfer. Is it like ftp://52.23.244.142:20 or ftp://52.23.244.142 ?

Comment: @Skyler The address is `52.23.244.142`. 20 is port. But FTP port is 21, not 20. And the FTP client will use it by default. If you have further questions, post a separate question on an appropriate site (like [su]).