# Create FTP and Mysql on Amazon Cloud Server - UI based - No linux commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I read the answers posted here [Setting up FTP on Amazon Cloud Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server) but I do not understand the Linux commands.

Why use Linux commands if Amazon has provided the UI

The amazon screenshots look like this, I am confused on how to create FTP, Mysql, activate PHPMyAdmin and get the IP address.

Is amazon so difficult so we have to understand all the Linux commands.Why do we need a Linux administrator to setup FTP and Mysql, isn't it pretty easy for any programmer to do it in cpanel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

cPanel is software that runs on a server to make it easier to manage that server. The AWS console is intended for, among other things, creating servers. After you create the AWS server you would then SSH into that server and install cPanel if that is something you want to run on your server.

If you want a server that already comes preconfigured with cPanel and whatever else, you can find things like that in the [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/ref=dtl_navhdr_header).

Note that AWS provides **Infrastructure As a Service** which is a completely different thing from the basic web hosting it sounds like you are looking for. If all you need is a basic web host with cPanel support where you don't have to know how use Linux then there are thousands of web hosting providers out there for you to chose from, and I'm sure some of them probably use AWS behind the scenes.