# How get ftp address with website name?

Tags: ftp, dns, ip-address

I used the info in the previous Stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server/37453330#37453330). It helped me achieve most of what I want. My address shows up like this: ftp://54.38.2.255//html/. I wanted to get the FTP to show up like I am used to e.g. ftp://mysite.com. Is this achievable? Also, the extra html on the end of my address is causing a problem in some scripts that I rely on. I want to be in the html directory, but show up like I desire. I confirmed Apache is running and phpMyAdmin is working, but a PHP script that unzips files to the server is not. Could this mean PHP is not working properly? Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general networking (dns specifically) tech support, And since you've shown no code, there's nothing for us to help you with.

Comment: If `mysite.com` resolves to `54.38.2.255` then `ftp://mysite.com` will go to `ftp://54.38.2.255`.  That's how DNS works.

Comment: Mine does not the first part works like you say. However, the ftp does not work with mysite . com it only works with 54.38.2.255

Answer (score 0):

Really two separate issues. First, you will need to register a domain from google domains or godaddy (any domain registrar). At that point you can point your newly registered domain to your IP address. Second, for your html issue you are pointing to a subdirectory in your html directory. You will probably need to change that directory in your web server configuration or in your php to point to the correct location.

Comment: My domain is registered and showing up. I have my site running and showing up. When I put in www.mystie.com it goes to it. I does not do it for ftp://mysite though. I have worked whit PHP access before, is the point to correct location don in httpd.conf file?

Comment: @bistel: PHP and HTTP have nothing to do with FTP.  Do you even have an FTP server running?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused on what you are trying to accomplish now. I thought you were having a DNS issue getting to mysite. Are you having trouble accessing [http]://mysite.com/html? Does mysite resolve to the correct ip?

Comment: [code]http://mysite[/code] or http://52.70.137.181 both work. When I try ftp://mysite it does not, it only works from the numbers like ftp://52.70.137.181. I can log in and transfer files.

Comment: You just said mysite and the ip works, but then said mysite does not work. Which part of mysite does not work? Ftp? Web (http)?

Comment: Sorry cannot seem to write lines in the editor. http : // with my domain name works. ftp only work with ip address.

Comment: Is the http server and ftp server running on the same server (ip)? Just to make sure, you aren't wanting mysite.com to point two different ips, one for ftp and the other for http requests.

Comment: they are on the same server. No I want them to be same. The FTP only wroks with ip address. My web address works fine with ip or domain name. I want the ft p: / / domain-name to work.

Comment: What ftp software are you using? What error message do you get? What client are you using? If the dns is indeed pointing to the correct ip address, there is a problem somewhere with your server configuration.

Comment: I am using AWS e2c with an elastic ip

Comment: Yes, but what FTP software are you using (client and server)? Did you change the port? How are you access it with your IP?

Comment: I got the ftp installed with $ yum install vsftpd. I added the ports like the post I show in original (post that I followed instructions) says. At top (original question) I link to the way I did it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in your client? Have you tried to access the FTP locally on the box with the domain name?

Comment: No real error. When I type in ft p:// mysite.com/ it just says "Server not found". When I type in ft p://my-ip I get prompted for user name and pass (like I want). When I type in htt p://mysite.com/ it loads my webpage when it type in htt p:// my-ip my site loads. I am confused?

Comment: try telneting into the ip and the domain to validate that it isn't a client configuration issue telnet <ip> port and see if you get a response. Do the same for domain telnet <domain> port. The only reason i can think is maybe wrong port? are you putting port with ip and not with domain?

Comment: Did telnet... thanks did not know how to use that. But same exact thing port 21 with domain no luck with ip worked fine.

Comment: Tried t0 use a third party program called GoodSync to do some other work(I used this with ftp to ip). I recieved this message. "144138 Error analyzing ftp://54.38.2.255/: listing folder with LIST: cannot open data conn: [connecting 108.142.120.62:1032]: Connection refused" does this offer any clues?

Comment: @bistel that sounds like a firewall issue. Can you make sure that the firewall is configured properly?

Comment: Wow, you and support from GoodSync both said the same thing! So tell me could this be the case if one program Directory Opus is able to connect? Does this make sense that some can and other can't based on a firewall? I am going to explore the possibilities of it being the culprit.

Comment: No it doesn't make a lot of sense that one program would bypass the firewall. There definitely is a configuration issue somewhere that is incorrect that is pretty silly I bet. If you can't get a single utility to work correctly using the domain, make sure that the domain is resolving correctly and to the same port. Amazons firewall and dns is pretty sophisticated so I bet something is getting lost somewhere. Have you tired from a different network? (maybe internal to Amazon)? Or if you are only testing internally test from outside of Amazon.