# How can I find my FTP credentials for my WordPress site hosted on an EC2 instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

This is my first time working with both AWS and WordPress. I bought a theme to install on my server and when I installed the recommended plugins I am now asked for my FTP information on a screen that looks like this:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWndF.png)

Where can I find this information from my AWS account (I assume?).

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server#11404078

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See also [tag:wordpress] tag description.

Answer (score 2):

EC2 instances do not come with built-in FTP access, you need to create it. Here is a very good guide form a developer I know: https://silicondales.com/tutorials/aws-ec2/setup-ftp-sftp/

Anyways, if you are not very proficient with server management but wanna keep your site on AWS, probably you should take a look at AWS Lightsail - https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/

Best,
Francesco