# using vsftpd to upload file into ec2 from browser

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vsftpd

I have set up vstfpd on EC2 Linux server using various resources including this:  [Setting up FTP on Amazon Cloud Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server/11404078#11404078) and I am able to start vsftpd:

```
Starting vsftpd for vsftpd: [  OK  ]
```

Have SG set up to allow access on ports 12000 - 12100 and have this set up on   vsftpd.conf as:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=54.175.227.189
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_max_port=12100
port_enable=YES
```

I can get SFTP working via FileZilla using my .pem file on local maching - but want to be able to have users upload files directly into this EC2 instance from their web browser (I am using PHP).  I've searched and cannot find any examples so am keen to get some information to help me move ahead.

thanks in advance!

kiteandwindsurfer

Comment: you cant find examples of uploading files via HTTP and PHP on backend? interesting

Comment: Thanks ilias-sp - I was able to get it working fine using S3 - but very odd that I cannot locate any examples of this functionality with EC2

Comment: Finally got a file upload to ec2 server working - using php to first upload the file to the default tmp directory (move_uploaded_file) and then copying the file to my local dir for that domain (copy).  What I found as an issue was that the tmp dir had a different owner than the local dir, thus had to change owner of local dir to same owner as the tmp (apache).  Now all is working, as it turns out was able to work around the need for vsftpd