# How to access my wordpress files in EC2 without using filezilla or other FTP?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-ec2, hosting

I need to change some lines in the wp-config.php code so I can change the URL of my wordpress site.

The thing is that I am completely new to Amazon Web Service and EC2. I am looking for something like File Manager in CPanel, but I can't find anything and they always say that you should connect by FTP using filezilla, for example, but I can't connect my FileZilla because it's giving me an error.

How can I acces my wordpress files without using FTP as filezilla?

Comment: Is an FTP server running on the EC2 instance? Did you configure the instance and load WordPress, etc, or did you use an existing AMI that had it pre-loaded? Unlike an ISP where you have shared access to a system (fronted by CPanel), you have the whole EC2 instance so it is up to your to manage/run it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt but you may have to use FTP or SFTP method to connect and access your files.

The filezilla must be giving you can error due to an step missed by you.

You can see below video tutorial which explains steps to connect EC2 using FileZilla.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI

Comment: Yeah but it's giving me an error (Can't connect the server). In some places they say that the user I must write is "ubuntu", but in your tutorial it says "ec2-user". How can I know which user should I use?

Comment: you need to create a new FTP user. please see following link to add a new FTP user. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server?answertab=votes#answer-11404078

OR 

https://qiita.com/alokrawat050/items/abb814dc9796d7f025b4